# naive bayes - Warning message: In data.matrix(newdata) : NAs introduced by coercion

Tags: r, algoritmo, machine-learning, aprendizagem-de-máquina

Consegui rodar o algoritmo naive bayes no R, porém estou encontrando problemas para fazer a matriz de confusão do resultado. Esta é a mensagem que recebo após realizar a predição com o comando `predict`:

> Warning message: In data.matrix(newdata) : NAs introduced by coercion"

Ao adicionar type='raw' ele roda, porém ao tentar fazer a matriz de confusão, obtenho o seguinte erro:

> Error in table(anatelteste$Condicao, predicao) :
>   todos os argumentos devem ter o mesmo comprimento

Este é o código que estou rodando:

```
library(e1071)
anatel <- read_csv("anatel.csv", locale = locale(encoding = "ISO-8859-1"))
amostra <- sample(2, 454, replace = T, prob = c(0.7, 0.3))
anatelTreino <- anatel[amostra == 1,]
anatelteste <- anatel[amostra ==2,]
dim(anatelTreino)
dim(anatelteste)
modelo <- naiveBayes(Condicao ~ GrupoEconNorm + CanalEntrada + Tipo + Servico
  Modalidade + Motivo, anatelTreino)
modelo
class(modelo)
predicao <- predict(modelo, anatelteste)
## quando eu chego aqui ocorre problemas de NA

Warning messages:
##In data.matrix(newdata) : NAs introduced by coercion

## eu usei type='raw' e consegui proseguir porem nao consigo fazer a tabela de confusao

predicao <- predict(modelo, anatelteste, type='raw')
predicao
confusao <- table(anatelteste$Condicao, predicao)

Error in table(anatelteste$Condicao, predicao): todos os argumentos devem ter o mesmo comprimento

CanalEntrada        Condicao  GrupoEconNorm Tipo       Servico                               Modalidade Motivo           
  <chr>               <chr>     <chr>         <chr>      <chr>                               <chr>      <chr>            
1 Atendimento Pessoal Encerrada Anatel        Reclamação Móvel Pessoal                       Pós-Pago   Cobrança         
2 Atendimento Pessoal Encerrada OI            Reclamação Móvel Pessoal                       Pós-Pago   Cancelamento     
3 Atendimento Pessoal Encerrada OI            Reclamação Serviço Telefônico Fixo Comutado -~ Local      Serviços Adicion~
4 Atendimento Pessoal Encerrada VIVO          Reclamação Móvel Pessoal                       Pós-Pago   Bloqueio         
5 Atendimento Pessoal Encerrada VIVO          Reclamação Móvel Pessoal                       Pós-Pago   Cobrança         
6 Atendimento Pessoal Reaberta  VIVO          Reclamação Móvel Pessoal                       Pré-Pago   Cancelamento
```

Comment: Bem-vindo ao StackOverflow em Português! Infelizmente, esta pergunta não pode ser reproduzida por quem for tentar respondê-la. Por favor, [dê uma olhada neste link](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/6700/como-fazer-uma-pergunta-reproduz%C3%ADvel-em-r/6701#6701) e veja como fazer uma pergunta reproduzível em R. Assim, as pessoas que desejarem te ajudar conseguirão fazer isto da melhor maneira possível.